# How To Extract Data From a Nested JSON File

Tags: python

I'm been working with this JSON data that shows the carbon intensity output for different fuel types regionally throughout Europe. I want to display the forecast number for each "short name" and have been having trouble doing so. I tried using the code below that states "for data in data: print(data[2]["regions"][3]["forecast"]). My explanation for my for-loop is that since "data" is a list, I wanted the "regions" area which I believe I can access through stating the second index. I then wanted the "intensity" element within the "regions" so I used the [3] index. I then wanted the forecast info thus why I stated ["forecast"]. Could someone please help me extract the forecast information for each area? Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
import requests
import pprint

filename = ("https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional")
r = requests.get(filename)
print("Status Code:", r.status_code)

#Store API responce in a variable
responce_dict = r.json()

pprint.pprint(responce_dict)

#Drawing Out Specifics
datas = responce_dict["data"]
#pprint.pprint(datas)


for data in datas:
    print(data[2]["regions"][3]["forecast"])
```

Comment: "Could someone please help me extract the forecast information for each area?" Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/. You have shown some code and explained your reasoning and how you are reflecting that in code, but you have not *asked a proper question* - you need to a) show exactly what goes wrong when you run the code, and b) explain why you are unable to solve the problem yourself, by showing [your research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) efforts.

Comment: Any number of things could be wrong, depending on both what the JSON actually looks like and based on what you think e.g. "second" and "third" mean (you do understand that Python lists are indexed starting at 0, yes?). That said, it isn't clear what you expect the loop `for data in datas:` to do. Doesn't your request give you a *single* chunk of data? Is the data a list at the top level? If so, do you actually want to iterate over that list? If it's a dict, are you trying to iterate over the values? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `intensity` key in the path to the forecast

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "from": "2021-08-24T00:30Z",
            "to": "2021-08-24T01:00Z",
            "regions": [
                {
                    "regionid": 1,
                    "dnoregion": "Scottish Hydro Electric Power Distribution",
                    "shortname": "North Scotland",
                    "intensity": {
                        "forecast": 343,
                        "index": "high"
                    },
```

I think what you want is

```
for data in datas:
    print(data[2]["regions"][3]["intensity"]["forecast"])
```

Comment: If that's the problem, then the question should be closed as not reproducible/typo; it boils down to simply not looking at the data closely enough, and answering it cannot realistically help anyone else who comes to the site.